# Vertical / Horizontal Accordion -- Swipe to reveal Images

Tags: android, image, accordion, swipe

Is it possible to have horizontal or vertical accordion animated effect that when i touch swipe it slides open / close images?  Are there any libraries i can plug into my source code?

For example:

http://tympanus.net/Development/VerticalSlidingAccordion/example1.html

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/images/

Under "Clip art, photos, and animation" you will see a horizontal display of 3 photos.  One photo is revealed in full while the other 2 are collapsed partially.  I must click it to reveal that one and collapse the other

Thanks